# How do i parse a variable in a function to being able to define which variable to send?

Tags: autohotkey

This is my code

```
IniRead, custommessage1, whisperconfig.ini, messages, Message1
IniRead, custommessage2, whisperconfig.ini, messages, Message2
^NumPad1::whispermessage(1)

whispermessage(var){
finalwhisper := "custommessage" + var ;this equals custommessage1
Msgbox, %finalwhisper%
BlockInput On
SendInput ^{Enter}%finalwhisper%{Enter} ;<-- problem
BlockInput Off
return
}
```

So in the first line i am importing the value of custommessage1 (it could be "hi im henrik"). This is what i wish to end up getting as a output.

Inside the function i want the var (which is 1 in this case) to be merged with a variable called custommessage ending with a result of custommessage1

i want the endresult to do a SendInput %custommessage1%.

this way i can have one function for up to 9 triggers including var numbers.

Can anyone help? i am sure this is fairly simple however i am new to this coding thing so bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function only knows about its own variables, the ones you pass in as parameters, and global variables.

You're trying to access `custommessage1`, which is outside the function and isn't global. You either need to make all your variables global, or pass them in to the function.

I suggest the latter, using an array. Here's an example, make sure you're running the [latest version of AHK](http://ahkscript.org/download/) for this to work properly.

```
IniRead, custommessage1, whisperconfig.ini, messages, Message1
IniRead, custommessage2, whisperconfig.ini, messages, Message2

; Store all messages in an array
messageArray := [custommessage1, custommessage2]

; Pass the array and message you want to print
^NumPad1::whispermessage(messageArray, 1)

whispermessage(array, index){
    ; Store the message at the given index in 'finalwhisper'
    finalwhisper := array[index]

    Msgbox, %finalwhisper% ; Test msgbox

    ; Print the message
    BlockInput On
    SendInput ^{Enter}%finalwhisper%{Enter}
    BlockInput Off
}
```

Alternatively, and this is outside the scope of your question, you could load the keys from the .ini file dynamically, meaning you wouldn't have to create new variables each time you added a key/value pair.

Here's how you could do that:

```
; Read all the key/value pairs for this section
IniRead, keys, whisperconfig.ini, messages
Sort, keys ; Sort the keys so that they are in order

messageArray := [] ; Init array

; Loop over the key/value pairs and store all the values
Loop, Parse, keys, `n
{
    ; Trim of the key part, and only store the value
    messageArray.insert(RegExReplace(A_LoopField, "^.+="))
}

; Pass the array and message you want to print
^NumPad1::whispermessage(messageArray, 1)

whispermessage(array, index){
    ; Store the message at the given index in 'finalwhisper'
    finalwhisper := array[index]

    Msgbox, %finalwhisper% ; Test msgbox

    ; Print the message
    BlockInput On
    SendInput ^{Enter}%finalwhisper%{Enter}
    BlockInput Off
}
```

Comment: this msgbox inside the function still prints out nothing and thus it does not work. the printing of the message does not work either. presumably due to finalwhisper not getting any value.

i did copy/paste all to make sure i didn't make spelling mistakes. Used first solution as i sort of grasp what you are saying there.. bear with my uber level of n00bness. hehe

Comment: oh btw also using latest. that error hit me last week. hehe

Comment: and pretty impressive how fast you coded those examples

i feel rather fortunate for your help. it is greatly appreciated

Comment: @HenrikBahneHansen Make sure you're running all the code in a separate script, and that the .ini file is in the same directory as your script, as that is the default location for AHK to look. Both examples work fine on my machine, so it's not a code-issue.

Comment: yeah got it working in a seperate file. working on implementing it now into full script.

Comment: @HenrikBahneHansen Nice, I suspect the `IniRead` part wasn't in the [auto-exec section](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Scripts.htm#The_Top_of_the_Script_the_Auto-execute_Section)? Would explain why you weren't getting any message at all instead of an `ERROR`.

Comment: found out why i was having some issues

Comment: I was trying to run script inside 

#SingleInstance force
#IfWinActive Path of Exile
{
}

Comment: i guess you did answer my question however i am back at square one. ill guess ill close the question and give up on this. it seems rather hopeless because of the scale of what im trying to do.